# How to set default gradle version (preferably to dynamic latest version) for flutter

Tags: flutter, gradle

So, I was having this problem, [Flutter Project Build Warning: Mapping new ns Error Solution](https://flutter-examples.com/flutter-project-build-warning-mapping-new-ns-error-solution/). And their solution works, but now it got me to think why I need to set
dependencies {
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0'
and to 7.0.4 and distributionUrl to 7.4 everytime I create a new project, can't I set the default version somewhere, so that every time I open a new project it's set to the latest version by default? Thanks for any help in advance.